# Android Getting a Contacts Name Keeps Returing a -1

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have an Intent that is sent to the Contacts Activity then the Main Activity gets the results in this Callback. The problem is that column is always -1. This being said how do I get the contacts name?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, 
                        projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
            if (column >= 0) {
                String name = cursor.getString(column);
                addString(name);
            } else {
                addString("Could Not Get User Name");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: column index of -1 indicates that the name of the column doesn't exist in cursor. Make sure you get the column name right.

Comment: That I understand. My thoughts are that it lies in: ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME. Without diving into the API doc I was wondering if anyone knows which column I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projection is `String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};` so the cursor will have only this column name, you need to use `String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};` to have access to Display_Name.

Also make sure that the ContentProvider returns the information you want.

Comment: Basically this equates to a SQL query kind of?

Comment: Yes, but the ContentProvider does the query for you, it's not necessary needed to be a database.